# PostgreSQL: Get rid of the 'a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"' error with a custom type?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to execute a query using dblink to get records from a table in a distant database, but I get the error 'a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"'. The solution is to give the expected columns in the query like `SELECT * FROM dblink('connname', 'query') AS (col1 type, col2 type, ...);` but it is not really practical to use. I tried to define a custom type `CREATE TYPE mytype AS (col1 type, col2 type, ...);` and passing it instead of the long annoying list of columns, but it doesn't work. Is there a simple way to simplify my queries ?

Comment: Maybe using foreign tables are a better solution?

Comment: Not in my case no.

Comment: Then wrap the query into a SQL function that is declared as `returns table`

Comment: Ok, I was hoping there was a simpler solution. I'll do that. Thanks.